# C# / BallonTip and timeout

Tags: c#, forms

I have an application, that uses some tooltips. The "Timeout" is driving me crazy by now:

No matter, what timeout value I provide in the following snippet: 
(Config is just a static class holding references during runtime)

```
 public static void notify()
        {
            Config.NotifyIcon.Visible = true;
            Config.NotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "BalloonTipText";
            Config.NotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "BalloonTipTitle";
            Config.NotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;

            Config.NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1 * 60 * 1000);
        }
```

The behaviour is "unexpected":

If I don't do anything, after the method is called - the BalloonTip stays unlimited it seems. (At least it was > 45 minutes by now)

But if the BalloonTip appears and I move the cursor - it vanishes after 2-3 seconds...

Test it on Windows 7 and Windows 10, both time the same problem.

Any Idea?

Comment: @NetMage Same Issue yes - but theres no "answer" about the behaviour. Workarounds are "cool" - but it doesn't answer the question about the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure not liking the accepted answer to a question it reason to duplicate the question? An interesting meta question...

Comment: In any case, your answer was in the answers for the duplicate question. I have copied the information here.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft says in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160065.aspx) for the `ShowBalloonTip` method that

```
This parameter is deprecated as of Windows Vista. Notification display times
are now based on system accessibility settings.
```

When you are not using the computer (moving the mouse or typing), Microsoft says:

```
In addition, if the user does not appear to be using the computer (no
keyboard or mouse events are occurring) then the system does not count this
time towards the timeout.
```